# Alineaciones y rellenos: ¿ Qué hace el compilador?

Tags: c

Tengo el siguiente código de prueba:

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct prueba
{
    long long c;
    double xx;
    int e;
    float b;
    short a;
    char ff;
    char d[5];
};

int main()
{
    struct prueba hh[3];
    printf("Size: %d\n\n", sizeof(struct prueba));
    for (int j = 0; j != 3; ++j)
    {
        printf("%d\n", &hh[j].c);
        printf("%d\n", &hh[j].xx);
        printf("%d\n", &hh[j].e);
        printf("%d\n", &hh[j].b);
        printf("%d\n", &hh[j].a);
        printf("%d\n", &hh[j].ff);
        for (int i = 0; i != 5; ++i)
            printf("%d\n", &hh[j].d[i]);
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Y me lanza como resultado 32 bytes como tamaño de la estructura.
Sin embargo, lo que no logro comprender es que algunos miembros tienen direcciones de memoria que no son múltiplo a su tamaño en bytes.
Yo compilé el código de prueba en Windows, donde mi maquina es de 32 de bits y me lanzó por ejemplo, en el primer miembro "c" una dirección de memoria que no era divisible a su tamaño.
Había leído que las direcciones de memoria de los miembros deberían ser divisibles a su tamaño en bytes porqué era más eficiente para el procesador, aunque desconozco el "porqué", me gustaría saberlo también sí es posible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Vamos a modificar un poco tu código: le quitaremos los *avisos* del compilador, y nos limitaremos a mostrar solo lo importante:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stddef.h>

struct prueba {
  long long c;
  double xx;
  int e;
  float b;
  short a;
  char ff;
  char d[5];
};

static void info( const char *n, size_t sz, size_t off ) {
  printf( "  [%s] offset: %zu, sizeof: %zu, alineado: %s\n", n, off, sz, off % sz ? "No" : "Si" );
}

int main( ) {
  struct prueba p;

  printf( "struct prueba: sizeof: %zu {\n", sizeof( struct prueba ) );
  info( "c", sizeof( p.c ), offsetof( struct prueba, c ) );
  info( "xx", sizeof( p.xx ), offsetof( struct prueba, xx ) );
  info( "e", sizeof( p.e ), offsetof( struct prueba, e ) );
  info( "b", sizeof( p.b ), offsetof( struct prueba, b ) );
  info( "a", sizeof( p.a ), offsetof( struct prueba, a ) );
  info( "ff", sizeof( p.ff ), offsetof( struct prueba, ff ) );
  info( "d", sizeof( p.d ), offsetof( struct prueba, d ) );
  printf( "}\n" );

  return 0;
}
```

Lo cual muestra el siguiente resultado:

> struct prueba: sizeof: 32 {
>     [c] offset: 0, sizeof: 8, alineado: Si
>     [xx] offset: 8, sizeof: 8, alineado: Si
>     [e] offset: 16, sizeof: 4, alineado: Si
>     [b] offset: 20, sizeof: 4, alineado: Si
>     [a] offset: 24, sizeof: 2, alineado: Si
>     [ff] offset: 26, sizeof: 1, alineado: Si
>     [d] offset: 27, sizeof: 5, alineado: No
>   }

Pues ya vemos que **se cumple**: todos los miembros (salvo el último) muestran `alineado: Si`.

Ok. Ahora, vamos a modificar un poco tu `struct`. Cambiemos el miembro `ff`, de `char` lo pasaremos a `int`:

```
struct prueba {
  long long c;
  double xx;
  int e;
  float b;
  short a;
  int ff;
  char d[5];
};
```

Ahora, la salida es:

> struct prueba: sizeof: 40 {
>     [c] offset: 0, sizeof: 8, alineado: Si
>     [xx] offset: 8, sizeof: 8, alineado: Si
>     [e] offset: 16, sizeof: 4, alineado: Si
>     [b] offset: 20, sizeof: 4, alineado: Si
>     [a] offset: 24, sizeof: 2, alineado: Si
>     [ff] offset: 28, sizeof: 4, alineado: Si
>     [d] offset: 32, sizeof: 5, alineado: No
>   }

Se sigue cumpliendo: todos (salvo el último) siguen mostrando `alineado: Si`.

> Había leído que las direcciones de memoria de los miembros deberían ser divisibles a su tamaño en bytes porqué era más eficiente para el procesador ...

Pues ya ves que **es correcto**. Se cumple en **todos** todos los casos ... **aparenta** no cumplirse en el último miembro porque `sizeof( X[] )` nos devuelve el tamaño **de toda la formación**.

> ...aunque desconozco el **porqué**

Muy sencillo. La idea es que el acceso a la memoria **es lento**. Entonces, de lo que se trata es de **minimizar** ese número de accesos. Y el bus de datos lee **en trozos discretos** de la memoria. Si el bus es de 32 bits, siempre leerá en dirección múltiplos de 4: 0, 4, 8, 16, ...

Si quires leer la posición 5, en realidad va a leer **siempre** a partir de la 4. Si el dato cabe, bien. Pero, si el dato no está bien alineado, pueda que tenga que acceder tanto a la dirección 4 como a la 8: 2 accesos, el doble de tiempo.

Comment: Tuve que eliminar el especificador %zu y reemplazarlo por %d, porqué el programa abortaba, lo depuré y salió que sobrescribe una dirección de memoria que el programa no tiene acceso. En fin, según tú, detectas si está alineado el miembro dividiendo el offset entre el tamaño y si el residuo es 1, no está alineado, si retorna 0, si está alineado. Pero se supone que se debe dividir la dirección de memoria por el tamaño del miembro para saber si está alineado o no; porqué el offset solo indica el desplazamiento de la dirección base hasta la dirección de memoria de un X miembro.

Comment: @MrDave1999 Si tienes que cambiar el `%zu`, un consejo: buscate un compilador que siga el estandar. Efectivamente, el *offset* es lo que es, el desplazamiento relativo desde el puntero base al dato. ¿ Podrías buscar un ejemplo, del tipo que sea, en el que el compilador genere una dirección de memoria **que no sea par** ? Fíjate que no digo múltiplo del tamaño de palabra, simplemente que no sea par. El compilador **siempre te va a generar direcciones alineadas**.